# Custom Font with ggsurvplot

Tags: r, fonts

I'd like to change the font of all of the text in my `ggsurvplot()` plot to Proxima Nova, which is saved on my local computer. I've imported the font into R using the `showtext` package, but I'm not sure how to adjust the `ggsurvplot()` code to accept a font outside of the ggtheme

```
library(showtext)

font_add("proxima", "~/Library/Fonts/Proxima\ Nova\ Font.otf")

ggsurvplot(
  surv_fit,
  data = df,
  title = "Survival by Neighborhood SES",
  xlab = "Time since hospital discharge (years)",
  ylab = "Survival Probability",
  legend.title = "Neighborhood",
  legend.labs = c("Prosperous", "Comfortable", "Mid-Tier", "At-Risk", "Distressed"),
  font.legend = 9,
  conf.int = FALSE,
  censor = FALSE,
  surv.scale = "percent",
  break.time.by = 2,
  pval = T,
  palette = c("#FFE082", "#FFB300", "#FF8F00", "#EF5350", "#B71C1C"),
  ggtheme = theme_classic()
) +
    theme(
      text = element_text(family = "proxima")
    )
```

When I add the `theme` lines, I get the error
`Error in ggsurvplot(surv_fit, data = df, title = "Survival by Neighborhood SES",  :  non-numeric argument to binary operator In addition: Warning message: Incompatible methods ("+.ggsurv", "+.gg") for "+"`.

I've tried adjusting `font.family` but it doesn't seem to recognize my preferred font. Is there a different package I should be using for custom fonts? How do I adjust my code to use the font I've loaded with `showtext`?

[image: ggsurvplot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! It looks like if you adjust the ggtheme line, you can add custom fonts:

```
ggtheme = theme_classic(base_family = "proxima"),
   font.family = "proxima"
```